# If post field is empty run another script

Tags: php, if-statement

This is my code:

```
<?php
$code = $_POST["code"];
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
Code:<input type="text" name="code"><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?
} else {
echo "".$code." <br />";
}
?>
```

I need to change it, so when "code" field is left empty, the script will run another script. Not sure how to do it, as if statement has been set at the 2dn line. Thanks!

Comment: Use `elseif (!isset($code)){ // Run another script }` ? Work out the logic and put them in the correct order.

Comment: this is easy man you should try things before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$code = $_POST["code"];
if (!isset($code)) {
// Run another script
}
elseif (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
Code:<input type="text" name="code"><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?
} else {
echo "".$code." <br />";
}
?>
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp) you can read more about if/elseif/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Put this where you want your other script to run.

```
require "otherscript.php"
```